# java pdfbox setting printer tray

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox, printers

I have been having a problem with setting the paper source on my printer directly with java. I want to be able to print from the printer's non-default paper source, using a custom size paper source. So the default source may be, tray 1 which contains A4, but I want the program to choose tray 2 with a non-standard paper size.

I have managed to get the tray ID by using code based on https://github.com/marco76/MediaTrayTest/blob/master/src/Main.java with changes to make it work with PDFBox.

I have tried the code using the ID I need, but the printer still prints from the default tray.

any thoughts?